# Dynamic filtering using lists, hide information until selected

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, filter, modern-experience, connected-web-parts

New to this forum, tried searching without any luck.

I wish to hide information from a list until a selection has occurred.

I'm using dynamic filtering.
Example I got two lists (List1, List2)

List 1:
Joe
Jack
Alex

List 2:

Street name, Phone Number,  Car,  etc

When you select Joe from list 1, only Joe's information shows up in List 2. But before you've selected anyone from list 1, the entire list 2 shows up.

Is it possible to have List 2 as hidden or shown as empty before the filtering has occurred (Selection in list 1) this to reduce confusion for users.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint online modern experience connected web parts? or anything else?

Comment: Yes, I'm using two regular list web parts in the online modern experience

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior of list web parts in SharePoint Online.

When there is no filter applied, list web parts shows all the items in corresponding list view (Selected in web part properties).

And there is no SharePoint out of the box way to hide list items before filtering in list web parts.

**Microsoft documentation**: [Dynamic list filtering](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-list-filtering-eed5f92e-1716-45d5-9a94-59decb930e42)

Answer (score 0):

Just like Genash said, this cannot be done with out of box dynamic list filtering.

Even if you create a new view to hide list 2 items, it will make the filter not work as there are no items can be displayed under that view. You will need to set a view which have required items displayed then you can filter

Answer (score 0):

Actually. Easy way. Just add a blank row, with some text stating what the user needs to do, and remove this from all views, except your Dynamic Filter view.